# Spring integration Kotlin DSL MessageChannels.publishSubscribe

Tags: generics, kotlin, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to work with Kotlin for Spring Integration with Java DSL.

From the Spring Integration Java DSL reference on GitHub https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/spring-integration-java-dsl-reference#message-channels I got this code snippet:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel publishSubscribe() {
     return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
}
```

When I try to rewrite this in Kotlin it is giving me some issues:

This code snippet below shows an error `Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter S`

```
@Bean
fun publishSubscribe(): MessageChannel {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get()
}
```

This code snippet throws an error:

> Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter S in fun !> publishSubscribe(): PublishSubscribeChannelSpec!
>   Please specify it explicitly.

So I converted it to this:

```
@Bean
fun publishSubscribe(): MessageChannel {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe<String>().get()
}
```

Which is throwing the following error:

> Type argument is not within its bounds:
>   Expected: PublishSubscribeChannelSpec!
>   Found:    String`

So the logical thing would be to replace the code like this:

```
@Bean
fun publishSubscribe(): MessageChannel {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe<PublishSubscribeChannelSpec<String!>!>().get()
}
```

And this is the next error:

> Kotlin: Unexpected token
>   Kotlin: Unexpected token

The unexpected token here is the exclamation mark.

So can I get this to work?

Comment: [String does not extend PublishSubscribeChannelSpec](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/ccb093bda59d1d97552500bc82a0b5b7eb86ef7a/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/channel/MessageChannels.java#L106)

Comment: I do not know what might have changed between when you posted this question and now, but your very first example without the types, compiles fine for me.